# JMeter Recovery testing

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, jmeter-plugins, recovery, recovery-testing

I would like to make [Recovery testing](http://istqbexamcertification.com/what-is-recovery-testing-in-software/) to server, I can simulate connection pool full with high load and thus failed in timeout to get connection.

I need to start my test with high load, reach a failure and decrease load gradually,

JMeter can't change it dynamically so I search for plugins and  [Concurrency Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ConcurrencyThreadGroup/) is doing the opposite, 
Increase it gradually, is there a way to make it decrease the value?

Is my only option is to start a new execution with decreased load?

> Recovery testing is done in order to check how fast and better the application can recover after it has gone through any type of crash or hardware failure etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done using vanilla JMeter without any plugins, JMeter acts as follows:

- All threads defined in the [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) are started within specified ramp-up period (here you can gradually increase the load)
- All threads start executing samplers upside down (or according to the [Logic Controllers](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#logic_controllers))
- When thread doesn't have any samplers to execute and/or loops to iterate - it's being shut down.

So given you gradually start your requests and thread group is not configured to run forever - the ramp-down should be pretty much the same as ramp-up. You can "help" JMeter a little bit using [Gaussian Random Timer](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Gaussian_Random_Timer), check out [How to Ramp Down in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-ramp-down-on-jmeter) guide for more details.

Comment: Ramp down using vanilla JMeter link is including Scheduler which will be removed next version, is there another option?

Answer (score 0):

I found a jmeter plugin [jp@gc - Ultimate Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/UltimateThreadGroup/) which I can start with high load by adding first row with high thread count and then decrease thread count by adding second (or more) row .